# a css style which makes buttons appear as light weight tab buttons

Tags: css

please provide links or write your own(extra points +1 too :-P )

using :- asp.net c# css vs08

### want

a style which makes button appear as tab, like that of stackoverflow.

the buttons like QUESTIONS, TAGS, USER, BADG,UNANS,ASK.

Comment: What html are you working with, and which particular StackOverflow buttons? There's quite a lot of them...

Comment: the buttons like QUESTIONS, TAGS, USER, BADG,UNANS,ASK.

Comment: Those aren't usually referred to as "tabs" - the ones below, for sorting answers: "oldest - newest - votes" - is what you normally get if you ask for tabs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<asp:Button ID="TestButton" runat="server" CssClass="SOButton" Text="Button Text" />

<style type="text/css">
    input.SOButton {
       border:none;
       background-color:#807F83;
       color:#FFFFFF;
       font-weight:bold;
       font-family:Arial,Liberation Sans,DejaVu Sans,sans-serif;
    }
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually mean button, as in:

```
<button>Button Text</button>
```

Either way, here ya go:

```
button.buttonclass,
a.linkclass {
    background: rgb(119,119,119);
    color: white;
    display: inline-block;
    font: bold 15px/1.4 Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    padding: 5px 15px;
}
```